# jquery function dropdown and button inputs

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have these two separate forms and i need the input to be sent to the jquery function below.

```
<select name="dropdown1" size=1>
<option value="1">1</option>
<optionvalue="2">2</option></select>
<button id='1' class='add1' value='57071e92ee31902f0a9ad392'>add1</button>

<select name="dropdown2" size=1>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option></select>
<button id='2' class='add1' value='57071e8bee31902f0a9ad0ec'>add2</button>
```

Up to now i managed to atribute to the var cardid the value of each button. but what about the var state? I need it to receive the value of the first dropdown menu in case the first button has been pressed or the value of the second dropdown menu in case the second button has been pressed.

```
$(function() {
$('.add1').click(function() {
var cardid = $(this).val();
var state = $('select[name="dropdown"]').val() // ??????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.add1').click(function() {
  var cardid = $(this).val();
  var state = $(this).prev('select').find('option:selected').val(); // get the prev select and find the selected option
  alert(state)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dropdown" size=1>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<button id='1' class='add1' value='57071e92ee31902f0a9ad392'>add1</button>

<select name="dropdown1" size=1>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<button id='2' class='add1' value='57071e8bee31902f0a9ad0ec'>add2</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.add1').click(function() {
var cardid = $(this).val();
var state = $(this).prev('select').val();
});
```